# Как вывести посты разных моделей у которых 1 общий тег?

Tags: laravel

Имеются модели изображения, видео, теги.

Для тегов использовал полиморфные связи (Many To Many (Polymorphic)) всё по доке.

```
class Tag extends Model
{
     public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Image', 'taggable');
    }

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Video', 'taggable');
    }
}
```

Пробую вывести пока так

```
 $tag = Tag::find(1);

        foreach ($tag->images as $image) {
            dump($image);
        }

        foreach ($tag->videos as $video) {
            dump($video);
        }
```

Но этот вариант мне не нравится, как можно сделать одним циклом?

Или вывести двумя циклами и объединить коллекции?

Answer (score 1):

у коллекций есть метод `merge`:

```
$tag = Tag::with(['images','videos'])->find(1);
$media = $tag->images->merge($tag->videos);

dump($media);
```

Comment: Спасибо, потом попробую

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в модель Tag еще одну связь `taggable` таким образом

```
class Tag extends Model
{
     public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Image', 'taggable');
    }

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Video', 'taggable');
    }

    public function taggable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Теперь все сущности с каким-то конкретным тегом вы можете получить без всяких циклов следующим образом:

```
$taggables = Tag::find(1)->taggable;
```

Ссылка на документацию: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships

Документация на русском: https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent-relationships#pl

Comment: Добавил, выводит null

Comment: Добавил ссылки на документацию, посмотрите, как там сделано